# Django tastypie , how to access the object created by post_list in ModelResource class

Tags: django, python-2.7, tastypie

here is my tastypie code snippet.

```
class MycustomeResource(ModelResource):
    asdf = fields.IntegerField('asdf', null=True)
    adsfasd = fields.IntegerField('adsfasd')

    class Meta:
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = Mycustome.objects.all()


    def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):

        object_temp = super(MycustomeResource, self).post_list(request, **kwargs)

        return object_temp
```

here `post_list` is creating on  object, I want that object , so that I can perform operations on it.

do I need to  override `obj_create` to get object..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, post_list method calls obj_create method of ModelResource class, and you can access your object inside it like this:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    bundle = super(MycustomeResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request)

    '''
    operations with your object bundle.obj
    '''
    return bundle
```

Comment: Ok thank you, where to write this obj_create function.?

Comment: inside your modelResource.